# What kind of 3-folds emerge after glueing hemispheres of 3-balls with tubes cut out?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

What kind of 3-folds $A$ and $B$ emerge after glueing the hemispheres of the 3-balls together as indicated in the picture?

My guess for the first one is a solid Klein bottle, but I'm not sure..

[image]

Comment: You should be more specific about gluing map. For instance, if I do not remove the tubes and use the equatorial reflection, then I get $S^3$, but if I use the antipodal map, I get $RP^3$. With other choices I can also get other lens spaces.

Comment: Sorry for not making this precise. I meant the equatorial reflection

Comment: Then both are just solid tori.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Really? For the first one, how to interpret the tube then? And for the second one, shouldn't there be a hopf link somewhere?

Comment: Oh, you are right, the second is a link exterior. For the first example, it is the complement to an unknotted solid torus, which is again a solid torus.